# Java Faster Equals method For float type

Tags: java, floating-point, set, equals

As I know set.add use equals method of FastFloat

For me important only first two digits after point(!!!), so in the equals method to make equals faster I use `Math.abs() >= 0.001` but I don't understand why this code return `2` instead of `1` because `Math.abs(3.54 - 3.5405) < 0.001`
Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class st {

public class FastFloat {
    private float ff;


    public FastFloat(float ff) {
        super();
        this.ff = ff;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + getOuterType().hashCode();
        result = prime * result + Float.floatToIntBits(ff);
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof FastFloat))
            return false;
        FastFloat other = (FastFloat) obj;
        if (!getOuterType().equals(other.getOuterType()))
            return false;
/*          if (Float.floatToIntBits(ff) != Float.floatToIntBits(other.ff))
            return false;*/
        if (Math.abs(ff - other.ff) >= 0.001)
            return false;
        return true;
    }


    private st getOuterType() {
        return st.this;
    }


}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Set<FastFloat>> lsff = new ArrayList<>();
    lsff.add(0, new HashSet<>());
    Set<FastFloat> sff = lsff.get(0);
    st x = new st();
    sff.add(x.new FastFloat((float)3.54));
    sff.add(x.new FastFloat((float)3.5405));
    System.out.println(lsff.get(0).size());
}

}
```

Comment: A floating point number in a computer doesn't have indefinite precision and can lead to stuff like this. It's a binary representation. So 3.54 can in fact be the same as 3.5399999999

Comment: Because your .hashCode(it does not truncate to 3 digits) does not match the .equals() method

Comment: That is not a valid definition of `equals`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `hashCode()` method gives different results for `ff==3.54` and `ff==3.5405`, so they are assigned to different buckets of the `HashSet` and your `equals` method is never used to test if they are equal.

If `a.equals(b)`, `a.hashCode()` must be equal to `b.hashCode()`. That's the contract.

From the `equals()` Javadoc :

> Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method, which states that **equal objects must have equal hash codes**.

Answer (score 1):

The type of almost-equals you are implementing does not meet [Object's contract for equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-), because it is not transitive.

Consider the case of 0, 0.0009, and 0.0018. `Math.abs(0.0009 - 0)` is less than 0.001, as is `Math.abs(0.0018 - 0.009)`, but `Math.abs(0.0018 - 0)` is greater than 0.001.

It is fine to have an almost-equals method, and use it in some contexts, but to make `HashSet`, and other hashing structures work, you need your `equals` and `hashCode` to conform to the `Object` contract.

If the only reason is "speed", get rid of the complications and use `Float`.

If you have some other reason for needing to group unequal floats together in your `HashSet`, there are many ways to divide them into equivalence classes, including the one discussed in [k5_'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38419673/1798593). You can also base it on pure floating point arithmetic, without having to extract and manipulate bit patterns. For example, base it on division by 0.001:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class st {

  public class FastFloat {
    private float ff;
    private float fudgeFactor = 0.001f;
    private float fudged;

    public FastFloat(float ff) {
      super();
      this.ff = ff;
      this.fudged = (float) Math.rint(ff / fudgeFactor);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      return Float.hashCode(fudged);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if (this == obj)
        return true;
      if (obj == null)
        return false;
      if (!(obj instanceof FastFloat))
        return false;
      FastFloat other = (FastFloat) obj;
      return Float.compare(this.fudged, other.fudged) == 0;
    }

    private st getOuterType() {
      return st.this;
    }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Set<FastFloat>> lsff = new ArrayList<>();
    lsff.add(0, new HashSet<>());
    Set<FastFloat> sff = lsff.get(0);
    st x = new st();
    sff.add(x.new FastFloat((float) 3.54));
    sff.add(x.new FastFloat((float) 3.5405));
    System.out.println(lsff.get(0).size());
    sff.add(x.new FastFloat(0f));
    System.out.println(lsff.get(0).size());
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement `.equals()`/`.hashCode()` for float with some floats being equal. So you can use your class with `HashSet` or `HashMap`.

One way of doing that is to strip the last <23 bits (as you remove binary places not decimal, to keep 4 valid decimal places thats about 10 binary places removed) from the `Float.floatToInBits()`. You use the resulting int in your `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` implementation.

I didnt do the math in binary so the numbers are not actually correct (examples if you do it in decimal)

- Something like 1000000 will be equal to 1000555 but will be different to 999999
- Something like 1,00101 will be equal to 1,0013 but different to 1,00099

This approach leads to a valid `.equals()`/`.hashCode()` but doesnt provide the Math.abs() < 0.001 you wanted (in same cases the abs will be much(!) higher and in some cases lower).  If that property is more important to you dont use `.equals()`/`.hashCode()` and create your own collections.